# Equivalent to cv2.INTER_AREA in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I tried to use the same transform as cv2.INTER_AREA in PIL for image reduction transform, but I couldn't find a resampling method with the "area" keyword.

Doesn't PIL provide corresponding transform?

Where I read resampling methods:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Resampling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before PIL 2.7 the Image.ANTIALIAS interpolation was the only one recommended for downscaling.
After 2.7 this changed (see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/2.7.0.html).
If you have the time/processing power, then Image.Resampling.LANCZOS is the best choice for scaling down images. There is no pixel-perfect equivalent to cv2.INTER_AREA in PIL.